# Active Storage in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am learning Ruby on Rails and I am stuck with Active Storage and uploading files. I am using this tutorial:

[Tim DiSabatino](https://www.timdisab.com/uploading-files-in-ruby-on-rails-with-active-storage/)

When running the project I see an error in terminal: *Unpermitted parameter: :header_image*

I double, triple-checked my code and in a desperate move I even changed the permissions in the entire project directory by *chmod -R 777*, but cannot get this error go away.

I am running the project on a remote unmanaged server by A2hosting.com with Ubuntu 20.04

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you must add header_image in strong parameters like this
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :header_image)
end

Answer (score 1):

refer to the official docs when in doubt
it is very clear and has code examples
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
in the model you have to define

```
has_one_attached :header_image
```

to attach the file once the form has been submitted

```
post.header_image.attach(params[:header_image])
```

the controller has 2 definitions of the same method and is only going to take one of the 2 possibilities
add the following edited from the tutorial

```
# /app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, files: [], :header_image)
end
```

header_images has to be added to the list of permitted parameters

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I overlooked that I had post_params defined twice in the controller.